# filtering and ordering firestore data flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter out posts hidden by the user, and order them by user stars and date. However, no matter how I use filters, I am getting different errors.

```
stream: postRef
          .where('hidingUserId', isNotEqualTo: firebaseAuth.currentUser)
          .where('stars', isEqualTo: 0<=5)
          .orderBy('stars', descending: false)
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
```

this code give error:

`The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([stars]), false], [FieldPath([timestamp]), true]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([hidingUserId])' when an inequality operator is invoked.`

Initially, I only user where on hidingUserId, but I got error saying that where() filter has to also be used on the orderBy() field. I cannot use isNotEqualTo filter twice. Then I tried using different conditions, but still getting errors. Or is there any other work about? Please, help! Thank you!

Comment: What does the .where('stars', isEqualTo: 0<=5)  do? Do you have docs where stars are outside that range? Cause if you don't you could potentially just remove that clause.

Comment: i did not have it initially. but the inequality filter must be used on the orderBy field... this is very confusing...

Answer (score 0):

The isNotEqualTo is considered an inequality. That means the first order by has to be on that field.

If that doesn't meet your requirements you can query for the data you need and then sort it afterwards.

A note on why that is the way it is:
Firestore is built to scale to handle massive loads of traffic. In order to do that they have to limit a lot of functionality available to normal sql databases and almost every query has to have an index. Those indexes and other limitations make it so that the data can be scanned in log n time instead of n  or n^2 or some other less efficient time.

Comment: thanks! but "If that doesn't meet your requirements you can query for the data you need and then sort it afterwards." can u give me a rough idea, how to sort it after the query?

Comment: You can write the query with just the where clauses and then in your flutter code do a .sort call on the results.